# Jenkins stuck at restaring slave agent

Tags: jenkins

Over the weekend, my Jenkins slave was down. Now it is up again, I can SSH from and to the master, so I expect Jenkins should be able to restart the agent on that slave. It is configured to be started via SSH.

What happens instead is that the master seemingly can't connect to the slave, the log shows exactly nothing.

What can I do to get this unstuck?

I tried already temporarily disabling and reenabling the node.

Comment: What OS is your master and the slave? What kind of connection are you establishing?

Comment: jenkins master won't be able to start the slave automatically. There has to be some configuration done on the node server. for e.g. if the node server is windows automatic restarts have to be handled at the node level..the jenkins master will just used the method to use the slave but the process/service at node should be running,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the master helped. My problem sounded similar to this [old Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19465), the workaround worked for me.